# Use Pages for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type I am generating in functions.php. I would like each post to be a page, rather than a post. How can I change this? I tried changing 'capability_type' => 'post' to 'capability_type' => 'page' - but this did not work.

```
// LFIO: Custom post type: Case Results
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_result' );
function register_cpt_result() {
    $labels = array( 

        'name' => _x( 'Case Results', 'result' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Result', 'result' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'result' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Result', 'result' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Result', 'result' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Result', 'result' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Result', 'result' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Case Results', 'result' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No case results found', 'result' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No case results found in Trash', 'result' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Result:', 'result' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Case Results', 'result' ),
    );
    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'My firm\'s case results',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,

        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'result', $args );
}
```

Comment: You are confusing two things - tha capability_type defines who has the right to edit/create this post type, and has nothing to do with being a post or a page.

Comment: What functionality are you hoping for from a page versus a post? In WordPress, Pages are just a different post type.

Comment: I'm hoping that this specific custom post type will use my normal page template, rather than create a special template for it. Of course, I will still have the archive template for this post type - but the actual posts themselves I would like to use the traditional page tamplte (page.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another easy method is for this to be the entirety of your `single-result.php`.

```
<?php
get_template_part( 'page' );
```

This will literally use your `page.php` file, no need to duplicate the content. That way, you won't need to make changes in 2 locations.

Comment: Wouldn't you use get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

Comment: @BradDalton that would attempt to load a template named `content-page.php`

Comment: ok but what if you named it single-result.php?

Comment: This would grab `page.php`, where `get_template_part('content','page')` would get `content-page.php`. `page.php` which will contain a bunch of things such as `get_header(); get_sidebar(); get_footer();` etc. that would be identical in both files.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hoping that this specific custom post type will use my normal page
>   template, rather than create a special template for it.

Here's a way to tell WordPress to load up the page.php template when your post type's single template would normally be displayed. There are many ways to accomplish this, but this particular approach has the advantage of not creating a duplicate template, which introduces maintenance overhead. Also, it's more performant because it saves WP from having to load up extra template files.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_136803_template_include' );
function wpse_136803_template_include( $original_template ) {
  if ( is_singular( 'your_post_type' ) ) {
    return get_template_directory() . '/page.php';
  } else {
    return $original_template;
  }
}
```

Replace `your_post_type` with the name of your post type. An array can be used if you need to check multiple post types. If you're using a child theme, you may want to replace `get_template_directory()` with `get_stylesheet_directory()`.

References:

- [Don’t use template_redirect to load an alternative template file](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/)
- [is_singular()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called single-result.php in your theme folder and copy/paste all the code from page.php

Further reading to fully understand why: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Another option which includes some of the same solutions already answered is to:

1. Copy your page.php file
2. Rename it to single-cpt.php where cpt is the singular name of your custom post type
3. And include support for page-attributes to your custom post type code

   ```
   'supports' => array( 'page-attributes' ),
   ```

Otherwise, you will not get Page Attributes in any of your single cpts.